# formatting ajax.actionlink text to display

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a decimal data type in my model and an annotation to format it so it adds commas after 3 digits:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###0.00}" + " (USD)")]
public decimal PaidAmount { get; set; }
```

when I have any `DisplayFor(m => m.PaidAmount)` the formatting displays correctly (1,200.00 USD). However, in Ajax.ActionLink the first argument takes a string for the text to display so I can't use a lambda expression (m => m.PaidAmount). When I do:

```
Ajax.ActionLink(Model.PaidAmount.ToString(), //rest of link params)
```

the formatting doesn't apply to the link text, it shows just a bunch of numbers without commas (1200.00 USD, note there is no comma after the 1)

my guess is that using the capital 'M'odel version of model loses its annotation properties, is there a way to go around this and apply the formatting to the ajax.actionlink?

Comment: The reason ActionLink doesn't use the data annotation is because it  just expects string for its text. It doesn't expect you to pass a model expression.  `m=>m.PaidAmount` exposes the property to `DisplayFor` so that it can retrieve model metadata/data annotations.  `ActionLink` doesn't expect these kinds of expressions though because you often aren't passing proeprties but instead things like `Ajax.ActionLink("Back to Home",`

Comment: I know that doesn't help, but just to help you understand the distinction between why one works and one does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(string.Format("{0:#,##0.00 USD}", Model.PaidAmount), ...)
```

Note I think you mean `0:#,##0.00` not `0:#,###0.00` (i.e. 10,200.00 USD, not 1,0200.00 USD)

Answer (score 2):

Data annotations will not work in this case as they are checked in HtmlHelpers and won't affect regular `ToString`.

You can create an extension method to format your number an call it in your view:

```
public static class Extensions
{    
   public static string ToCurrency(this decimal number)
   {
       return number.ToString("{0:#,###0.00}") + " (USD)";
   }
}
```

**In you view:** (don't forget to reference the Extensions class either directly in the view or in web.config under views folder)

```
Ajax.ActionLink(Model.PaidAmount.ToCurrency(), //rest of link params)
```